Laravel Mysql Wildcard not pulling all results
I have this Laravel query which searches two fields in the table (name, introduction) for matching entries:
$data = Listing::select("name", "slug")
            ->where("name", "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
            ->orWhere("introduction", "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
            ->get();

Everything works fine, except, when the "Open ter" is supplied as the search item ($), it does not pull results yet there is an entry with name "Open Terms Archive". When I provide "Terms" as the query, the entry is included in the results.
My database collation is utf8mb4_general_ci. What could be the issue here?

try  using DB::raw to normalize the data.
->where(DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '  ', ' ')"), "LIKE", "%{$q}%")

@AkinniyiAkinbodeBolade same issue

Have you tried an equivalent raw SQL statement to see if there's maybe another issue with your query? In your SQL Editor (not Laravel's Eloquent), run SELECT * FROM listings WHERE name LIKE '%Open ter%' OR introduction LIKE '%Open ter%';. If that returns results, then it's an Eloquent issue, but if it doesn't, then there's another underlying issue. That all being said, I don't see any issues and can't trigger any issues with equivalent data locally...

@TimLewis the SQL run fetches results in SQL editor but same raw query as below returns 0 results:
$q = $request->query->get('query');
$data = \DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT name, slug FROM listings WHERE name LIKE :search1 OR introduction LIKE :search2"), [
'search1' => '%' . $q . '%',
'search2' => '%' . $q . '%'
]);

Hmm, again, not seeing any obvious issues at a glance... Are you connected to the same database? And are you sure the queries are exactly the same? They look the same, but if you use something like DB::enableQueryLog(), then run your query, then you can run DB::getQueryLog() to see the specific query being run.

You can remove multi spaces by trimming first. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
$q = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $q));

$data = Listing::select("name", "slug")
    ->where(DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '  ', ' ')"), "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("REPLACE(introduction, '  ', ' ')"), "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
    ->get();

Another approach is to use Collate. A collation orders characters based on weights. Each character in a character set maps to a weight. Ch
$data = Listing::select("name", "slug")
    ->where("name", "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
    ->orWhere("introduction", "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("name COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci"), "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("introduction COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci"), "LIKE", "%{$q}%")
    ->get();

Collate helps with string comparison and sorting.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/adding-collation.html#:~:text=A%20collation%20is%20a%20set,orders%20characters%20based%20on%20weights.

Same issue with both approaches.
